# Templated snprintf

Tags: c++, templates, printf

I need to convert some numbers (integers and doubles) into std::strings, and for performance reasons cannot use stringstream (we found it to be very slow when used concurrently)

It would be nice to be able to do something like

```
template<typename T>
static const std::string numberToString(T number)
{
    char res[25];
    // next line is a bit pseduo-y
    snprintf(res, sizeof(res), "%T", number);
    return string(res);
}
```

But I'm not really sure how is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: std::to_string(number)

Comment: [in case you wanted the link: `std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: I will investigate to_string as to whether it suffers from the same contention issues as stringstream

Comment: Hmm, `stringstream` by itself should not be that slow, it calls the C++ formatters and  just uses an in-memory buffer. But converting a float or double to a string is indeed a complex operation. Why do say that stringstream is too slow? And have you already profiled your application to identify bottlenecks?

Comment: Key part is used concurrently, this was on gcc 4.4.7 on rhel7. We found that in a single threaded case performance was fine, but in some tight loops with many threads going it was awful. I imagine this may be fairly specific to our application but it is a bottleneck

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea. Use:

```
template<typename T>
static const std::string numberToString(T number)
{
    char res[25];
    snprintf(res, sizeof(res), getPrintfFormat<T>(), number);
    return res;
}
```

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template <typename T> struct PrintfFormat;

template <> struct PrintfFormat<int>
{
   static char const* get() { return "%d"; }
};

template <> struct PrintfFormat<float>
{
   static char const* get() { return "%f"; }
};

template <> struct PrintfFormat<double>
{
   static char const* get() { return "%f"; }
};

template <typename T>
char const* getPrintfFormat()
{
   return PrintfFormat<T>::get();
}

template<typename T>
static const std::string numberToString(T number)
{
    char res[25];
    snprintf(res, sizeof(res), getPrintfFormat<T>(), number);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << numberToString(10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << numberToString(10.2f) << std::endl;
   std::cout << numberToString(23.456) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10
10.200000
23.456000
```

It also provides a level of type safety. With the posted code, using

```
std::cout << numberToString('A') << std::endl;
```

will result in a compile time error.

Comment: Are you sure that it will be faster that C++ stringstream? Anyway it is a nice template usage :-)